# We have two branches in TFS(Standard and Enterprise) of which many of the files are common. How do we manage changes in both?

Tags: tfs, branch

We have two folder structures in TFS(two separate branches) for same application. One branch managing normal desktop application and another with client-server architecture. 
The later one has extra features. Apart from few files, most of the files are common between the branches.

If we have a change, we have to do it in both the structures. We want to minimize this by using single copy of common files. Is there any way we can keep all the common files in a one folder structure and application-related files in different folder and still build the solution with out any issues?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to make changes in both structures? Branches typically allow you to merge changes between branches without much manual labour. See the [branching and merging primer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730834%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to get started.

If you make the Enterprise folder your main branch, and make your changes here, you can port your changes on a regular basis to the simpler Standard branch.